# How to add child documents to solr?

Tags: python, json, solr, nested, parent-child

I am new to Solr and the documentation can be hard to follow sometimes.

What is exactly needed to index the following json object into a core, so that the child documents appear as shown here below?:

```
json2 = [
 {'id' : '1', 
  'language':'nl', 
  'name' : "Caroline",
  '_childDocuments_' : 
  [
    { 'id': 'doc_1', 
     'type_s': 'document', 
     'text': "this is the text",
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

When I index this into the core, the `'_childDocuments_'` nested document does not appear. This is what I get instead:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1603113431913"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"doc_1",
        "type_s":"document",
        "text":["this is the text"],
        "_version_":1680986266766671872},
      {
        "id":"1",
        "language":["nl"],
        "name":["Caroline"],
        "_version_":1680986266766671872}]
  }}
```

I read that I need to specify the `_root_` in the schema, and I have, although I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. What exactly else should I be doing to index this as desired ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/indexing-nested-documents.html ? If anyone is going to be able to say if you're doing it correctly, you'll have to say what you're doing and how you have specified `_root_`.  You probably also want the nest path fields as shown in the reference guide.

Comment: I think my issue was that I was working with the managed-schema , so I tried to create my own schema and define the root as displayed in the documentation link you shared. My issue is that I dont know how to define a schema, so that the child documents appear as I would like them to. Is there any example schema out there I could play around with that configures a child document? I am having difficulties finding examples of complete schemas that show what I want to do.